# MYSQL avg time in where clause

Tags: mysql, performance

Two columns in the table **cityWalkStartTime** and **cityWalkEndTime** , with timestamp.

Looking for a query which will return the row id, for the minimum time difference.

```
Select rowId,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(cityWalkEndTime,cityWalkStartTime)) from walks where  <time diffence is minimum in the entire database>
```

Also, if I want rows which have time-diff less than 10 seconds.

```
Select rowId,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(cityWalkEndTime,cityWalkStartTime)) from walks where  <time diffence is < 10 seconds>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:
Minimum value in database with corresponding rowId:

```
Select rowId,MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(cityWalkEndTime,cityWalkStartTime)))
from walks 
GROUP BY rowId
ORDER BY MIN(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(cityWalkEndTime,cityWalkStartTime))) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Just the values <10s

```
Select rowId,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(cityWalkEndTime,cityWalkStartTime)) 
from walks 
where TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(cityWalkEndTime,cityWalkStartTime))<10;
```

Comment: Any performance enahncement for the second query as TIMEDiff is called twice , one in select query and other in where clause

Comment: Theoretically you can write `SELECT rowId,td FROM (SELECT rowId,time_to_sec(etc) AS td FROM walks) w WHERE w.td<10;`. However with the internal optimization of MySQL it might not make a difference (test and see)

Comment: Subqueries rarely speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

This avoids calling TIMEDIFF twice.  (It probably does not speed things up enough to notice.)

```
Select  rowId,
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(cityWalkEndTime, cityWalkStartTime)) AS diff
    from  walks
    HAVING  diff < 10
```